# jqGrid + editGridRow + add new row + hide/show columns + again add new row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using this command for adding a new row. It pops up the window with fields that needs to be added.

```
jQuery("#editgrid").jqGrid('editGridRow',"new",{height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:false});
```

Now, based on a functionality I hide and show some columns in the same grid "editgrid" and when I click add row, it again shows the same previous fields instead of new ones.

eg. when I load the grid first, I show ['Date','Client','Amount'] columns. When I click add new row date, client, amount fields are shown in the pop up. Now based on the functionality, I hide Date, client and amount fields and show ['Tax','Total','Closed'] fields. When I click add, it again show the same previous fields date, client,amount. But it should show tax, total, closed.

Please help!!!

Thanks

Comment: would be better if you share the code, your explanation is quite hard to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you can solve the problem using additional property [recreateForm:true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#properties):

```
jQuery("#editgrid").jqGrid('editGridRow',"new",
                           {height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:false,recreateForm:true});
```

Comment: @Tivakar: You are welcome! By the way for about two years ago I had the same problems as you. I spend about two days in debugging of jqGrid till I understood why sometimes the settings of Edit and Add dialog will be mixed. Starting with the time I overwrite some jqGrid defaults with respect of `$.extend($.jgrid.edit, {recreateForm: true /*... some other settings*/});`. I recommend you to do the same